# Mac Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-mac

Can anyone advise how you show files/folders not included in a project on the Mac version of Visual studio?

I've looked through every menu I can find and cant figure how!?

Answer (score 1):

Add folder to workspace, If I understood you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the relevant option:

Right click on root solution, click display options, select show all files.

[image: Right click on root solution, display options, show all files]